# Action specific JS Script just like view scripts

Tags: zend-framework

By default, every action has its specific view script like `index.phtml` for `index` action. However more to this, I also want to have js script specifics to actions as well. like `index.js` for `index` action.

I tried to use $this -> view -> headScript() -> prependScript('myjsfile.js');, but the script is added to top and not at the bottom as I was hoping for. I suppose a helper would do the trick. but i dont know how to create it. or there is a better solution of what i am hoping for.

Even though I appendFile from the action, the files which are appended from the layout file always seems to come at last. Which is not what I want, I want files in the layout file to be loaded first and then the script provided in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('myjsfile.js');
```

instead of prepend!

you can altough define an order for the files:

```
$this->headScript()->offsetSetFile(1, 'myjsfile1.js')
                   ->offsetSetFile(2, 'myjsfile2.js');
```

Comment: `appendFile` or `prependFile` both gives the same output. and setting offset is not so much pratical in realtime cases, as the scripts can grow and shrink as per requirement, so fixing a order is not what i want. I want the script to be placed at the end.

Comment: Well i `echo $this->headScript()` just before closing the body tag, so everything i add via `appendFile()` will be at the end. So the method provided by ArneRie is precisely what you need :)

Comment: @Sam but the scripts are not added in the last order despite using appendFile

Comment: I dont know if you guys are understanding my problem or not because, even though I appendFile from the action, the files which are appended from the layout file and always at last. Which is not what I want, I want files in the layout file to be loaded first and then the script provided in the action method